# How to request for Zoho authorization from an ASP.NET Core React JS?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core React Js app that is currently integrated with Zoho API(s). It is using OAuth 2.0, so it prompts the user for a confirmation/acknowledgment.

Question: How can I integrate react with zoho WITHOUT the user confirmation/acknowledgment? I thought this can be achieved by have an ASP.NET Core web API make the initial Zoho API calls (to retrieve access token...etc). But unfortunately im getting an error when I make the request.

I am following this documentation: https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/web-apps/authorization.html

I've done & verified the following things:

- Zoho API Console client (i used the "Server-based Applications" client).
- I double checked the client Id and redirect URI is what I'm using.
- From my API controller, I am making the following request:

  ```
  var url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=" +
           "<MY CLIENT ID>" + "&prompt=consent&response_type=code&scope=ZohoMail.accounts.READ,ZohoMail.folders.READ,ZohoM 
        ail.folders.UPDATE&redirect_uri=" +
       "https://localhost:7070/oauthredirect";

  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
  var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  ```

This http request is returning an "Internal Server" error.

Is it possible to make a Zoho authorization request from the server-side? If so, what might I be doing wrong? And what should the redirect url be in this case (i.e. i am assuming this would allow the bypassing of the user's confirmation/acknowledgment).

Comment: Please, check if this page can be useful:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v3/auth-request.html#self-client
It's the right way if your API Client is a standalone server application with no user interface.

And then follow:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v3/access-refresh.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my original post w/ clarifications. But to summarize it here, my ultimate goal is to integrate with zoho API without having the user confirmation/acknowledgment screen.

Comment: In the documentation, the "Self-Client" is the right way to do that. What is stated in the page (read Self-Client Option) I posted is:
"You can also use this option when your application is a standalone server-side application performing a back-end job."
And you don't have to call the ouathredirect URL, as it is the way to ask user's authorization. You should use the bearer token. So, I think you basically want to call Zoho's API and get JSONs or perform some UPDATE/DELETE operations, without the user interacting with Zoho's login screen, right? If so, let me find some snippets I can share.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. If you want to let a user log in with his/her account, you can do that with oauth2 protocol only with the redirect. That's the way the oauth2 specifications work. Otherwise, you must use a backend user to perform API calls. I don't know if I have explained it well. Please let me know what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to automatically log in a user, you cannot do that, you must redirect the user to Zoho's oAuth redirect page. It's the way the oAuth2 works.

Comment: The self client says it is for testing purposes.

Comment: @ManedWolf, thanks it does make sense. I believe what I need is a service account in order to avoid the acknowledgement prompting on the UI side. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to register a backend user (let's call it service account). You'll get an API token, and you can browse Zoho's API with that token.

Comment: Any documentation on this? Curious if there is anything that distinguishable a "backend user" from a regular user? Is this registration done thru the self-client under zoho console?